# Adding values of small arrays to positions in a greater array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, scikit-image

I have the following problem. I have an array with shape (21,41,91). Now I need to fill given line coordinates in the box array with ones. Now I want to add skimage balls to that coodintates in the box array, so that the surrounding ball coordinates get also ones in the boxarray ( adding the balls to that line coordinates). First of all, can I somehow feed the box array with the indices of the line, and put the value 1 to that coordinates in the box array? And how do I then add the ball coordinates to the box array?

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.morphology import ball
box = np.zeros(21,41,91)
ball1 = ball(3)
linecoordinates = np.array([[ 14,11,35],
 [ 13,14,37],
 [ 11,17,38],
 [ 11,19,41],
 [ 12,21,43],
 [ 15,24,46],
 [ 18,27,46],
 [ 19,30,45],
 [ 20,33,45],
 [ 21,36,46],
 [ 22,37,47],
 [ 24,37,47],
 [ 23,40,49],
 [ 24,42,51],
 [ 21,44,50],
 [ 19,46,48],
 [ 18,47,45]])
```